# SuperGrub2Disk not booting from USB

Tags: boot

I have downloaded SuperGrub2Disk and installed it via unetbootin on my USB. When restarting and opening the boot menu I can see the USB there. WHen choosing it the boot menu disappears but appears again after a second!?

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure that you start this process without your usb plugged into the computer. Otherwise extract it.
- Run:

> mount

- Save somewhere the mount output or just make you open a new terminal when running mount again later. As an example output might be:

> /dev/sda6 on / type ext3 (rw,errors=remount-ro,commit=0)
>   tmpfs on /lib/init/rw type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,size=5242880,mode=755,size=5242880,mode=755)
>   tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=755,size=10%,mode=755)
>   proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
>   sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
>   udev on /dev type tmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
>   tmpfs on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,size=20%,mode=1777,size=20%,mode=1777)
>   devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=620,gid=5,mode=620)
>   /dev/sda9 on /home type ext3 (rw,user_xattr)
>   fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
>   binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)

- Insert your usb. In most Gnu/Linux systems it will be automounted. Otherwise mount it manually.
- Close the Nautilus / Dolphin window that has just appeared.
- Run again:

> mount

- Take a look at its output. As an example it might be:

> /dev/sda6 on / type ext3 (rw,errors=remount-ro,commit=0)
>   tmpfs on /lib/init/rw type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,size=5242880,mode=755,size=5242880,mode=755)
>   tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=755,size=10%,mode=755)
>   proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
>   sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
>   udev on /dev type tmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
>   tmpfs on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,size=20%,mode=1777,size=20%,mode=1777)
>   devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=620,gid=5,mode=620)
>   /dev/sda9 on /home type ext3 (rw,user_xattr)
>   fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
>   binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
>   /dev/sdc1 on /media/UNI type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,uid=1000,gid=1000,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,uhelper=udisks)

- Compare the first and the second mount runs. Detect one more line in the second run.
- Line should be something as:

> /dev/sdc1 on /media/UNI type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,uid=1000,gid=1000,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,uhelper=udisks)

- Now let's focus at first part of it: /dev/sdc1
- Usb Partition device (the mounted one) is /dev/sdc1
- Usb device is /dev/sdc (Note that the partition number has been lost. That it is right.)
- Umount the partition device

> sudo umount /dev/sdc1 # Ubuntu users
>   umount /dev/sdc1 # Non sudo distributions

- Now we are going to dump the Super Grub2 Disk.
- **REMEMBER THAT YOU WILL LOOSE ALL THE PENDRIVE CONTENTS**
- Make sure to adapt the command to your needs:
- Change /home/user/Desktop for the actual path for you super grub2 disk iso file. You might want to use /tmp
- Change super_grub2_disk_1.99b1.iso for the iso filename that you have downloaded.
- /dev/sdc should be your usb device.

> sudo dd if=/home/user/Desktop/super_grub2_disk_1.99b1.iso of=/dev/sdc

- Just to be sure we will finish with:

> sudo sync

- That's it! Usb device is bootable and should contain Super Grub2 Disk.

`

Comment: I followed every single step, but I still get the same result. The USB shows up in the boot menu, but after selecting it the boot menu shows up again after a second...

Answer (score 0):

I have tried Unetbootin for Supergrub2disk but it did not work either.

Instead try this:

Make sure you have a USB with a partition and NOT the whole device being used as a filesystem (If the device was /dev/sdx, there should also be a /dev/sdx1).

Instructions:

1) Open super_grub2_disk.iso with the Archive Manager (file name will be different).

2) Copy the folder named 'boot' to your USB.

3) Install grub onto MBR of USB with the specified boot directory.
change x to usb device (find it with lsblk or fdisk -l or Disk Utility).
Change directory of /media/USB/boot to the location of where the folder 'boot' was copied to.

Try:

> $ sudo grub-install --no-floppy --boot-directory=/media/USB/boot /dev/sdx

or if it didn't work:

> $ sudo grub-install --no-floppy --force --boot-directory=/media/USB/boot /dev/sdx

You can add your own .isos to /boot/boot-isos on the USB drive this way too.
The iso file should have grub in it (such as Ubuntu's .iso file).

This didn't work on a machine that used grub 1.99 or efi so also see this link:
http://www.supergrubdisk.org/wiki/SGD_Howto_make#How_to_make_a_Super_Grub2_Disk_USB